# JavaScript - Making a Div look like it is a 3-D button with box-shadow

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Dynamic and Draggable Divs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dynamicDivs.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="touch-buttons-grid">

        <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 1</div>

        <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 2</div>

        <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 3</div>

        <div class="touch-button-spots"></div>

        <div class="touch-button-spots"></div>

        <div class="touch-button-spots"></div>

    </div>

    <script src="dynamicDivs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I was making this project, I wanted to do a few things with the blocks labeled Block1, Block 2 and Block 3:

1. Change the color based on the "click" event.
2. On the "mousedown" event, I want the boxes to look like it is being pressed down and not have the "shadow" effect.
3. On the "mouseup" event, I want the boxes to have the box-shadow property based on the style changes in the "click" event.

My JavaScript code worked for Goal #1.  For Goal #2 and Goal #3, it only works when the blocks are blue and not red.

In the following code, I was expecting my box-shadow property to be manipulated properly along with the position properties 'top' and 'left'.

Here is my JavaScript code (and it's Vanilla JavaScript!).  This is where the problems occur:

```
const touchButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".touch-button");

let draggedElement = null;

function toggleTouchButtonColor(event) {

    if (event.target.classList.contains("touch-button")) {

        event.target.classList.add("touch-button-click");

        event.target.classList.remove("touch-button");

    } else if (event.target.classList.contains("touch-button-click")) {

        event.target.classList.add("touch-button");

        event.target.classList.remove("touch-button-click");

    }

}

function mouseDownTouchButton(event) {

    event.target.style.top = "5px";

    event.target.style.left = "5px";

}

function mouseUpTouchButton(event) {

    event.target.style.top = "0px";

    event.target.style.left = "0px";

}

touchButtons.forEach(function (touchButton) {

    touchButton.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownTouchButton);

    touchButton.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpTouchButton);

    touchButton.addEventListener("click", toggleTouchButtonColor);

});
```

Here is my CSS styles sheet for your reference:

```
#touch-buttons-grid {

    width: 90%;

    height: 200px;

    margin: 10px auto;

    margin-top: 20px;

    background-color: rgba(220, 200, 10, 0.5);

    border-radius: 10px;

    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);

    align-items: center;

    justify-content: center;

    z-index: 1;

}

.touch-button, .touch-button-spots {

    width: 40%;

    height: 50px;

    margin: 5px auto;

    padding: 5px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    font-size: 20px;

    text-align: center;

    z-index: 5;

    position: relative;

}

.touch-button {

    background-color: rgba(60, 95, 240, 0.5);

    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(60, 95, 240, 0.25);

}

.touch-button-click {

    width: 40%;

    height: 50px;

    margin: 5px auto;

    padding: 5px;

    border-radius: 10px;

    background-color: rgba(220, 41, 10, 1);

    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(220, 41, 10, 0.5);

    font-size: 20px;

    text-align: center;

    z-index: 5;

}

.touch-button-spots {

    width: 50%;

    height: 60px;

    background-color: rgba(61, 54, 54, 0.75);

    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(61, 54, 54, 0.5);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fix it:

#### 1) Modify javascript to account for applying functions to `.touch-button-click` classes as well

#### 2) Use the CSS pseudo-classes `:hover` and `:active` to animate HTML button clicking

#### 3) You were missing `position: relative` from the CSS for `.touch-button-click`

E.g.,:

```js
const touchButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".touch-button");
const touchButtonsClick = document.querySelectorAll(".touch-button-click");

let draggedElement = null;

function toggleTouchButtonColor(event) {

  if (event.target.classList.contains("touch-button")) {

    event.target.classList.add("touch-button-click");

    event.target.classList.remove("touch-button");

  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("touch-button-click")) {

    event.target.classList.add("touch-button");

    event.target.classList.remove("touch-button-click");

  }

}

function mouseDownTouchButton(event) {

  event.target.style.top = "5px";

  event.target.style.left = "5px";

}

function mouseUpTouchButton(event) {

  event.target.style.top = "0px";

  event.target.style.left = "0px";

}

touchButtons.forEach(function(touchButton) {

  touchButton.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownTouchButton);

  touchButton.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpTouchButton);

  touchButton.addEventListener("click", toggleTouchButtonColor);

});

touchButtonsClick.forEach(function(touchButtonClick) {

  touchButtonClick.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownTouchButton);

  touchButtonClick.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpTouchButton);

  touchButtonClick.addEventListener("click", toggleTouchButtonColor);

});
```

```css
#touch-buttons-grid {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 200, 10, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.touch-button,
.touch-button-spots {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.touch-button {
  background-color: rgba(60, 95, 240, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(60, 95, 240, 0.25);
}

.touch-button-click {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 41, 10, 1);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(220, 41, 10, 0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.touch-button-spots {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(61, 54, 54, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(61, 54, 54, 0.5);
}

.touch-button:hover {
  background-color: #0a5699;
  filter: brightness(0.85);
}

.touch-button-click:hover {
  background-color: #9b1d07;
  filter: brightness(0.85);
}

.touch-button:active,
.touch-button-click:active {
  filter: brightness(0.65);
  box-shadow: unset;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Dynamic and Draggable Divs</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dynamicDivs.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="touch-buttons-grid">

    <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 1</div>

    <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 2</div>

    <div class="touch-button" draggable="true">Block 3</div>

  </div>

  <script src="dynamicDivs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  I did not realize that I needed to add the position: relative property in my "touch-button-click".  I also learned something about the "inset" and "unset" properties for "box-shadow".